# How to make the first element on an array the last?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Top Trumps style game, where once one side wins, they get the other's card, which works fine, but then they have to put their card 'to the back' which I'm struggling with. How do I move an element to the end?

```
if pWin == True:    # If the player wins, they get the computer's card
    player.append(computer[0])
    computer.pop(0)

else:   # If the computer wins, they get the player's card
    computer.append(player[0])
    player.pop(0)
```

Comment: "To the back" meaning...? This looks like it's successfully putting `computer`'s "first" card at the end of `player` when `pWin == True`. Isn't that "to the back" of `player`? A [MCVE] (including inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs) would help a lot here.  Side-note: If you prefer, you could combine these operations into a single line, since `pop` returns the removed element, e.g. `player.append(computer.pop(0))`. Also, if these sequences are of any real size, you should know that `list.pop(0)` is a O(n) operation; you may want to use `collections.deque` (where `popleft` is O(1)).

Comment: To put the first element in list `lst` to the back: `lst.append(lst.pop(0))`

Comment: @Primusa thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be adding/removing items from both ends of a list, consider using a [double-ended queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).